# accidentally deleted partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I am having some trouble with my laptop.
I had win 7 64 bit preinstalled on laptop and recently installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I was trying to find what could be the worst case for my laptop..I opened win 7 and went to disk management where I deleted the volume where ubuntu was installed.. when after restarting it showed no grub file found (the multi boot file), I took my pen drive and opened ubuntu from it as a trial.. Now there I deleted the space utilized by win 7 (i.e. C Drive).
I did not  deleted it completely. I kept some files there. I didn't touch the system reserve file.. now I restarted the laptop.. it doesn't go ahead because it has no "complete OS boot option"  haha.. I have found that creepy situation..

I now want to format all partitions from my hard drive and start it as a fresh one..
for that I want to enter the COMMAND PROMPT that comes after booting from win7 cd and then enter DEBUG commands for formatting hard drive.

what should be the commands?

Comment: We do not support Windows. Please visit http://superuser.com/

Comment: You did not do this accidentally, you did this intentionally. And what is your problem? Windows Installer _can_ erase all partitions and make your disk like a fresh one. More, Ubuntu LiveUSB _can_ delete all the partitions. And this is Ubuntu site so asking here _how to do something in Windows_ is not very polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot Ubuntu from your pen drive. Open the GParted application. If it is not installed, you can install GParted from the terminal by running: `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Open the GParted application. GParted is a partition manager with an easy to use graphical interface. You can use GParted to partition your laptop's hard drive any way you want to. For example, if you want to make a fresh partition for reinstalling Windows 7, you can make an NTFS partition for that.